# How to adjust autogenerated paths in cmake

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, setuptools, python-wheel

I am trying to build the following git: https://github.com/pupil-labs/apriltags under Windows 10.
It consists of a C-Library that is accessed via a python wrapper and can be installed into your python environment via pip.
While it is possible to just install it directly from PyPi, i want to install it from a local folder, since I am editing the C-Library to my liking.
It is recommended to use Visual Studio as a compiler, since i don't have a license, I am using the MSVC Buildtools.

CMake version is 3.24, MSVC is 19.33

I adjusted this in the setup.py to cmake_args.append("-GNMake Makefiles").
The C-Library is build, the problem comes when the project is installed.

```
Install the project...
      -- Install configuration: "Release"
      -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/../Bit_Punkte/Bit_pattern/Test/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.8/cmake-install/src/pupil_apriltags/lib/apriltag.lib
      -- Installing: C:/Users/../Bit_Punkte/Bit_pattern/Test/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.8/cmake-install/src/pupil_apriltags/lib/apriltag.dll

      copying src/pupil_apriltags\bindings.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-install\src/pupil_apriltags\bindings.py
      copying src/pupil_apriltags\__init__.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-install\src/pupil_apriltags\__init__.py

      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-install\src\pupil_apriltags\bindings.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-install\src\pupil_apriltags\__init__.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\cmake-install\src\pupil_apriltags\lib\apriltag.dll -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags\lib
      copied 2 files
      running build_ext
      installing to _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags\bindings.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags\lib\apriltag.dll -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags\lib
      copying _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pupil_apriltags\__init__.py -> _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags
      copied 4 files
      running install_egg_info
      running egg_info
      writing src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      removing '_skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info' (and everything under it)
      Copying src\pupil_apriltags.egg-info to _skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_skbuild\\win-amd64-3.8\\setuptools\\bdist.win-amd64\\wheel\\.\\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt'
```

The Problem starts i think with the `\wheel\.\` path. Under Windows a folder cannot be named "."

Since I am new to Cmake, Makefile and Setuptools, the only way I could think of helping me,
was to see if a path was hardcoded and the error was somewhere there.
I have found nothing like that.
So the conclusion is, that the problem lies in the generation of the path.
And here my knowledge of Cmake, etc. is to small to know where the problem lies.
Any Suggestions where to look further?

Greetings

Comment: Isn't `\.\\`` just ignored as `.` is the current folder?

Comment: The folder `..\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info` exists, looked it up in the explorer, the folder `..\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.8\setuptools\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info` does not exist. Thats where my assumption comes from, that the dot makes it all fall apart.

Comment: Not sure if Explorer is a good indicator. Maybe try to do `cd <path>` to change into that folder. If I enter `cd C:\Users\name\.\git` in the shell, it works and I am in `C:\Users\name\git` afterwards. Entering the same path in Explorer gives an error message

Comment: You are absolutly right. So its not the path. 

Checked the files, ` error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_skbuild\\win-amd64-3.8\\setuptools\\bdist.win-amd64\\wheel\\.\\pupil_apriltags-1.0.4.post10.dev0+gfff8536.d20230821-py3.8.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt` makes sense, in that the file is not there.